# SharePoint Developer Documentation

Tags: sharepoint, documentation

I will be needing to write some pretty comprehensive documentation for an upcoming project and was wondering if anyone has seen any samples of good documentation for SharePoint solutions.

E.g. What should go into the documentation for:

- a custom site definition
- a feature
- a custom web part
- a custom workflow
- etc etc etc

Any samples out there would be great.  I have a good idea of the kinds of things to include but would be interested to see some best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to **capture the business reason** for why these things came into existence in the first place. Including the original requirements in the documentation gives context, particularly for understanding what a feature was designed for to help plan its requirements for the future. It's also a helpful reference when the customer suddenly wants a feature to do something it was never designed for.

Another useful thing to record is **dependencies**. This is particularly true when a developed artifact can show up in different places, for example in a feature or site definition XML file as well as a page layout.